# Visit visa for the UK. Currently unemployed but I have sufficient bank balance

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

I'm a Pakistani, currently unemployed. I want to visit my brother, who lives in England and can sponsor me. I have enough bank balance to support myself too.

I'm single and unemployed. Is it possible for me to get a visa? The recent job I had was for a year and I was let go in May 2018. I'm a dentist by profession. Before applying for a new job I want to travel a bit. So is there any chance of getting a visa?

Comment: You need to demonstrate that you can support yourself during your visit, that you won't work illegally, and that you'll return home after your visit. Being single, unemployed and with a family connection in the UK you're probably going to find the last of those difficult to demonstrate to the satisfaction of an ECO. You can apply, but I wouldn't rate your chances highly.

Comment: Your current situation makes it next to impossible to get an UK visa. You cannot prove you are going to return back without a job in Pakistan, unless you have land/property in Pakistan.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? He has funds and can sponsor himself.

Comment: `I'm single and unemployed. Is it possible for me to get a visa?` - **Yes** `Before applying for a new job I want to travel a bit. So is there any chance of getting a visa?` **Yes**